# MySQL alias calculation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

It confuses me.. total left calculation seems doesn't work.

I am trying to get the total voucher and get total used and the total left.

please help.

```
SELECT 
 (IFNULL(SUM(value), 0)) AS total_voucher,
 (
  SELECT 
    IFNULL(SUM(value), 0))
  FROM 
    voucher_history 
  WHERE 
    idUser = 1 AND isUsed = 1 AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime)) = '2014-03-04'
 )  AS total_used,

 (total_voucher-total_used) AS total_left

FROM 
 voucher_history 
WHERE 
 idUser = 1 AND isUsed = 0 AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime)) <= '2014-03-05'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with conditional aggregation, rather than using a subquery:

```
SELECT coalesce(SUM(value), 0)) AS total_voucher,
       sum(case when is_used = 1 then value else 0 end) as total_used,
       sum(case when is_used = 1 then 0 else value end) as total_left
FROM voucher_history 
WHERE idUser = 1 AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime)) <= '2014-03-05';
```

Your query has the problem that it is trying to use column aliases (`total_voucher` and `total_used`) in the same `select` statement.  SQL does not support this.  You would need to use a subquery to get that functionality.

Comment: wouldn't `coalesce(SUM(value), 0))` return 0 even if only one value is NULL?

Comment: @VolkanUlukut . . . No, not at all.  `sum()` ignores `NULL` values.  It would only return `0` if *all* the values were `NULL`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i am try to get total_used on specific date with **where statement** and isUsed = 1. any idea?

Comment: @tonoslfx . . . There should have been no condition on `isUsed` in the `where` clause.  I left that in because it was in the original query.  If you want it for all users, remove the condition on `idUser`.  If you want it *by* user, then remove the condition and add `group by`.